# Sql server table copy from on database to another

Tags: sql-server

I want to copy data from `dbase1.stockmaster` to `dbase2.stockmaster`. Two of them having different columns.`dbase1.stockmaster` doesn't have a primary key. but I need to insert certain auto increment numbers to `dbase2.stockmaster` table p.k field. `dbase2.stockmaster` contains certain data which are referred on some other tables.

**EDIT:** (Adding below comment as a part of question)

```
declare @i int 
set @i=0 

while(@i <(select count(*) from NW000030.dbo.STOCKMST0001)) 
begin 
set @i=@i+1 
INSERT INTO NW000071.dbo.STOCKMST0001 (Stock_ID,ITEMCODE, ITEMNAME,RPROFIT1, RPROFIT2, RPROFIT3, QTY, LC, OLC, EANCODE, MRP, OPSTOCK, OPLC)
SELECT @i,itemcode, itemname, rprofit1, rprofit2, rprofit3, qty, lc, oLc FROM NW000030.dbo.STOCKMST0001 
end
```

Comment: What you have tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following format:

```
Use Database1

Insert into Schema1.Table1(columns)
select columns from Databse2.Schema2.Table2
```

Comment: if your primary key is a identity, you don't need to set value for this, and if your primary key not a identity column, you can use ROW_NUMBER to assign value to this.

Comment: Thanx a lot mehdi lotfi. while i give rownumber(),its got worked